# Refreshing a page with resubmitting a form in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web page that has a form on in.
sometimes when I submit the form the server does not answer;
so I want to refresh the page with resubmitting my form.

When I do this manually, an alert appears and asks me whether I like to resubmit the form or not,
but when using selenium (chrome driver + python) this alert does not appear.

What is the solution?

I used:

`driver.refresh()`

but no alert appears and form does not submit.

Comment: perhaps, somehow the site detects the automation. can you provide the URL if it's public? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AjeetVerma I can't provide the URL of the site I am working on, but I have found a test form [here](https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/basic-html-form-test.html) and the behavior here is similar to the other site, i.e. when I refresh the page, the resubmission alert does not appear.